# When creating a block through a transaction, is it proper to write the device's private key as a signature on the block?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I want to create a block-chain environment for devices.
When creating a block through a transaction, is it proper to write the device's private key as a signature on the block?

Answer (score 0):

Never (ever) reveal the private key for anything - person, phone or device.   The public key is what is shared with other parties.

WRT blockchain and especially Hyperledger Fabric, transactions submitted are signed with the private key and the signature is actually around a transaction containing the public key.

Answer (score 0):

That's a huge security flaw and defeats one of the key benefits of BC. Look at your private key as your private password to your bank account, laptop, phone among others.  You definitely don't want anyone know about it.

Short answer, No!

Happy coding.